# How to improve performance on screencasts with audio using GStreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, webcam-capture, screencast

I try to write a GStreamer pipeline to capture the screen, put a box on the corner capturing the webcam and record audio (all at the same time).

If I hit Ctrl+C to stop after ten seconds, for example, I realize I only record about 2 seconds of video (and audio). Actually, I don't care that the recording were done in real time, but I just want that GStreamer records the full lenght it should be.

This is the pipeline I have so far:

```
gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug=3 ximagesrc use-damage=0 \
    ! video/x-raw,width=1366,height=768,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert \
    ! videomixer name=mix sink_0::alpha=1 sink_1::alpha=1 sink_1::xpos=1046 sink_1::ypos=528 \
    ! videoconvert ! queue max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 \
    ! vp8enc ! webmmux name=mux ! filesink location="out.webm" \
    pulsesrc ! audioconvert ! queue max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 ! vorbisenc ! mux. \
    v4l2src do-timestamp=true ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240,framerate=30/1 ! mix.
```

I hope to have a solution, thank you.